# Jmeter encoding of URL path

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have an **URL path**

```
path=mcat official mcat critical analysis and reasoning skills question pack volume 1 online.html
```

I want to encode with **-** in place of **spaces**.

```
e.g-mcat-official-mcat-critical-analysis-and-reasoning-skills-question-pack-volume 1-online.html
```

How will I do this in jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [__strReplace](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) function which is available via [Custom Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) bundle of the [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project. You can install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager). The syntax would be

   ```
   ${__strReplace(${path}, ,-,)}
   ```
2. If you don't want (or cannot use) the plugins you can achieve the same using __groovy() function, in this case the syntax will be:

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.get('path').replace(' '\, '-'),)}
   ```

Both examples assume that your URL is stored in `${path}` JMeter Variable.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Replace Character in URL]

Comment: In some case instead of spaces underscore is coming so I want to replace underscore with '-' also